# How to exclude only the rows with flag=1 for the type=coverage?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table sales with columns : salesid, flag, type. flag could be 0 or 1 and type can have several data like 'CCO', coverage,  ..etc.

How to exclude only the rows with flag=1  for the type=coverage?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results, and your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the or condition in order to select all the data that is not type=‘coverage’ and then select the data that is type=‘coverage’ and flag=0.

```
Select * from sales where (type!= 'coverage') or (type= 'coverage' and flag = 0)
```

Comment: Or `WHERE NOT (type = 'coverage' AND flag = 1)` maybe?

Answer (score -2):

How to exclude only the rows with flag=1 for the type=coverage?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    sales 
WHERE 
    type = "coverage" 
    AND flag != 1;
```

Table schema and data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sales;
+---------+------+----------+
| salesid | flag | type     |
+---------+------+----------+
|       1 |    1 | coverage |
|       1 |    0 | CCO      |
|       2 |    0 | coverage |
+---------+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Exclude rows with flag=1 for the type=coverage?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sales WHERE type = "coverage" AND flag != 1;
+---------+------+----------+
| salesid | flag | type     |
+---------+------+----------+
|       2 |    0 | coverage |
+---------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Strings are delimited by single quotes.

Comment: I expect to get two rows in your exampel     1 |    0 | CCO    and       2 |    0 | coverage

Comment: You want to exclude rows with both type = "coverage" and type = 1?

Comment: Refer the other answer provided. It produces the result set you are expecting. If it satisfies your requirement, accept that answer.

Comment: Note OP wanted an answer in SQL Server - not MySQL.